# Excel Conditional Formatting: compare id description in sheet 1 to id description in sheet 2 if not a match highlight description in sheet 2

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

we have two sheets sheet1 has ID, description, method and sheet2 has ID, description, method

sheet1 contains such values:

ID   Description   Method

1|a|z

2|b|z

3|c|z

4|d|y

sheet2 contains such values:

ID   Description   Method

1   b        z

1   a        z

2   b        z

3   c            z

4   d            y

4   a            y

I need to match the ID in sheet 1 to the ID in sheet 2 and check to see if the Description in sheet 1  matches
the description in sheet 2 else highlight the description in sheet 2.

So far I can do a conditional formatter if the id is not in both sheets but I am not sure how to do a conditional formatter by matching the id and then comparing the descriptions such that if they do not match the description is highlighted in sheet 2. any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the description column in Sheet2 and create a CFR based on this formula,

```
=not(countifs(sheet1!a:a, sheet2!a1, sheet1!b:b, sheet2!b1))
```

Format with a fill color. It will be filled if not a two column match.

Comment: This was spot on. Thank you very much for your assistance.